# Obtaining a step function given a condition

Tags: calculus

Find a step function s such that
$$\int_{0}^{2} s(x) dx=5 \quad \int_{0}^{5} s(x) dx=2$$
The given answer is 
$$s(x)=\dfrac{5}{2} \quad \text{if} \quad 0 \leq x < 2$$

$$s(x)=-1 \quad \text{if} \quad -2 \leq x \leq 5$$

I don't understand how does one arrive to this solution.. even graphically trying to understand it I didn't come to a solution. Can someone please help me figure out how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the given answer. The definition of the step function $s$ should be
$$
s(x) = \begin{cases}\frac 52 & \text{if } 0\leq x<2\\ -1 & \text{if } 2\leq x\leq 5\end{cases}.
$$
Now, the simplest step function one can think of is of the form
$$
s(x) = \begin{cases}s_1 & \text{if } 0\leq x<2\\ s_2 & \text{if } 2\leq x\leq 5\end{cases}
$$
for some $s_1,s_2\in \mathbb{R}$, since the definition intervals are related to the extremes of the integrals. Imposing the condition given by the first integral you obtain $s_1=\frac 52$. Then 
$$
\int_2^5 s(x)\,dx = \int_0^5 s(x)\,dx-\int_0^2 s(x)\,dx = -3,
$$
and by using this second fact you can find $s_2=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions. The way to arrive at this one is to ask yourself: if the function is constant on $[0,2]$, what must its value be for the integral to be 5? The answer, clearly is $\frac{5}{2}$. The integral of the function on $[2,5]$ must be $-3$, so that again if you assume a constant value on that interval, the function is $-1$ on $[2,5]$.

There are other solutions: for example, $s$ could be $2$ on $[0,5/4]$, $-2$ on $[2,3]$, and zero elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Consider it as an area between the graph and the x-axis. Step functions create *rectangles*.

The first part indicates a rectangle with a base of $2$ ($x$ ranges from $0$ to $2$) and an area of $5$, so it's height is $\frac 52$.

The second part implies that $$\int_2^5 s(x) dx = -3$$
So the second part of your graph has a rectangle with a base of $3$ ($5-2=3$) and an area of $-3$ (which is just an area of $3$ underneath the axis). This gives a height of $-1$ in that range.